# UIImageView error no visisble @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to create a new UIImageView and display it on the main view but im getting the error no visisble @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView' when I call `[self.view addSubView:newBullet];`

heres the full method

```
- (UIImageView *)shootNewBullet {
    UIImageView *newBullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, playerShip.center.y,15,3)];
    newBullet.Image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"bullet2.png"];
    newBullet.hidden = NO;
    bulletMovement = 7;
    [self.view addSubView:newBullet];
    return newBullet;
```

the method is also in the .h file as `-(UIImageView*)shootNewBullet;`
Am I supposed to connect this to the view somehow?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [-[UIView addSubview:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a) not `addSubView`. Note the case, ObjC is case sensitive.

Comment: ahhhhh, if that was the problem I will give you my life

Comment: that was the problem, I owe you my life

Comment: new question, the entire view is being refreshed every time I call that method, every other uiimageview i have is being recreated